# InstallShield 12 Installer crashes

Tags: windows-7, crash, installshield

I am trying to install our application on a customer's Windows 7 Enterprise workstation and having the following problem: The installer always crashes when it is being run, there is no popup to alert me to the fact but the executable just closes quietly and an Application Error (EventID 1000) event is generated in the Windows Application log. Here are the details from the event:

```
Faulting application name: AudioNetV6.exe, version: 12.0.0.58849, time stamp: 0x45b1a378
Faulting module name: AudioNetV6.exe, version: 12.0.0.58849, time stamp: 0x45b1a378
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0001e7b9
Faulting process id: 0x1594
Faulting application start time: 0x01cdbda82c3d5878
Faulting application path: C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\WDT\AudioNetV6.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\WDT\AudioNetV6.exe
Report Id: 6caa7aaa-299b-11e2-a661-0019b942720b
```

I have tried the following steps to resolve this so far, none of which have made any difference:

- Running using As Administrator
- Made sure that the current Windows user is a member of the Administrators group
- Set the compatibility mode to *Windows XP (Service Pack 3)*

The installer will install perfectly well on Windows 7 Professional systems on other sites. The installer was created as a single exe installer using InstallShield 12 Professional and has not been modified in a long time. I don't know if this a problem with Enterprise or if there is a permissions problem or what. The system is using Symantec Endpoint Security but unfortunately I do not have access to the configuration of it. The system is a member of the customer domain and the current user is a domain user.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like a user account permission problem.  You will need to work with the IT staff to resolve this conflict.

Comment: That was my first thought but the user is registered as an Administrator on the local system. Also, why would the program crash? I could understand if a warning was displayed or the program just didn't run at all.